# Why is Grid.Column horizontal iniside Grid.Row?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to mock-up a faux news website to learn semantic-ui grid. I am trying to divide a row vertically into 2 smaller columns, but they are dividing horizontally and acting like more rows. How can I divide the row into two vertical columns?

So far my layout is a Row split into 2 columns (which works fine). the second column i have split into 2 rows (which also works fine). it's when i want to divide one of these rows into 2 columns things get wonky.

The styling is is for visualization since I'm just laying out empty boxes because there's no real content since it's just a layout.

```
    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column
        width="11"
        style={{ height: "500px", border: "2px solid black" }}
      />
      <Grid.Column
        width="5"
        style={{
          border: "1px solid black",
          padding: "0"
        }}
      >
        <Grid.Row style={{ height: "50%", border: "1px solid black" }}>
          <Grid.Column
            width="8"
            style={{ height: "50%", border: "1px solid black" }}
          />
          <Grid.Column
            width="8"
            style={{ height: "50%", border: "1px solid black" }}
          />
        </Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Row style={{ height: "50%", border: "1px solid black" }} />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
```

The first row in the second column is being divided, but into 2 horizontally instead of vertically as expected.[screenshot of inspctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r9ck.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will help you achieving your goal:

```
<Grid columns={2}>
  <Grid.Row>
    <Grid.Column style={{ height: "500px", border: "2px solid black" }} />
    <Grid.Column style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} stretched>
      <Grid columns={2} stretched>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} />
          <Grid.Column style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} />
          <Grid.Column width={16} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} />    
        </Grid.Row>  
      </Grid>
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

As you can see you can make it work with embedding another Grid into your second column. With the right props you do not even need to specify heights (as visible).

See it working here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/nkkmzl3lz0